# C++ Primer (5 ed) Exercise 1.20 What does this mean?

Tags: c++

I am learning how to program for the first time. I am using C++ Primer (5th ed). English is not my first language. Can you help me understand what the author is asking in Exercise 1.20?

> Exercise: 1.20: http://www.informit.com/title/032174113 contains a
>   copy of Sales_item.h in the Chapter 1 code directory. Copy that file
>   to your working directory. Use it to write a program that reads a set
>   of book sales transactions, writing each transaction to standard
>   output.

Comment: Frankly, it can't be explained more verbosely than it already is. If you have troubles with English, please take some English classes. What do you wish to know?

Comment: Off-topic for requesting translation/clarification services, rather than coding assistance.

Comment: include Sales_item.h to your project and use its methods to read some transactions and write it to console

Comment: It is this part that I find confusing: "Use it to write a program that reads a set of book sales transactions..."

Comment: To clarify, "the working directory" is the folder where you run your compiler. The same folder as your main.cpp.

Comment: What does the author mean when he says "read?" Do all I have to do is: std::cin? I don't get this part.

Comment: It means to include it in a source file, and use the types and procedures to write the code needed. Your lessons have covered `#include` and `<#include>` directives. It sounds like you need to go back over the prior lessons.

Comment: @ Ken: Thank you! I have done exactly that. Yet I wasn't sure it was the right thing to do. There are no answers in the back of the book.

@ Ken and Vexquis: I don't need any homework help. I am learning how to program because I want to learn. A friend is helping me. He is occupied today. I didn't want to bother him. So I came to this forum. My English is good but there are times when I just can't figure out what someone is saying.

Comment: @ĀnándéQìdàn I wasn't trying to imply you want homework help - even if was the case, it would be irrelevant to the problem. It's not about your desire to learn, it's about the usefulness of your question and the possibility to answer it. Currently, one can only guess what you meant by your question, because a) we're not the book authors, b) we can't read people's minds, so we can't know *What does the author mean when he says "read?"* because c) you haven't provided enough input to get output from people...

Comment: @Vaxquis: It is better to ask (when you can) if you don't know than to assume things. Anyway. I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The author wants you to copy the C++ header file, 'Sales_item.h', into a new folder where you can work with it.

Although I don't have the book, I would guess that the header contains a class describing a particular transaction, and you are supposed to write a program which instantiates (creates) an object for each 'transaction' you have, and then send it to standard output, probably using `std::cout`.

The class might contain a `print()` function, or perhaps a `friend ostream& operator<<` or similar, in which case you could use that function to output the required data.

Comment: ... and we're down to basically guessing. *sigh*

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much! That's what the header file is for. It describes what "item" (a term in the book) does. Your answer makes a lot of sense!